# Batch Contact creation/update with contact photo

Tags: c#, performance, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am using EWS managed API to create and update contacts on the Exchange Server.

I am creating a contact like this (where user is an Active Directory Principal object with some custom properties):

```
Contact addContact = new Contact(service);
exchangeContact.NickName = GenerateNickName(user);
exchangeContact.DisplayName = exchangeContact.NickName;
exchangeContact.FileAs = user.DisplayName;
...
exchangeContact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.BusinessPhone] = user.Phone;
exchangeContact.PhoneNumbers[PhoneNumberKey.MobilePhone] = user.MobilePhone;

ExtendedPropertyDefinition adGuidPropDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "ADGUID", MapiPropertyType.String);

exchangeContact.SetExtendedProperty(adGuidPropDef, user.Guid.ToString());

if (user.ThumbnailPhoto != null)
{
    exchangeContact.SetContactPicture(user.ThumbnailPhoto);
}

exchangeContact.Save(parentFolderId);
```

This code part is called for around 500 * 500 contacts, and it is taking too long. I am looking to improve its performance. I tried to use the [batch create/update methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn645424(v=exchg.150).aspx) but I found out they do not support "attachments", and that a contact photo is an attachment.

Is there another way to lower EWS calls or improve performance otherwise in this case?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can use to batch the Attachment creation but when you say 500 * 500 contacts are you creating 500 contact in 500 different mailboxes. That is to say you creating the same 500 contacts in each of those different mailboxes ?. If that's case the fastest way would be to create the contact once in a Master Mailbox and then copy the contact in to each of the Target Mailboxes. If you batch everything bar the Add Attachments that should give the best result.

Comment: Is there a way to copy multiple contacts at once? Or do you mean to call copy for every contact?

Comment: Sure you can batch Copy Item I'd probably limit it to 50-100 per batch or you might get timeouts.